# ctrl+c not associate with SIGINT in C

Tags: c, linux

I have tried this code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>

void sighandler(int);

int main()
{
   signal(SIGINT, &sighandler);

   while(1) 
   {
      sleep(1); 
   }
   return(0);
}

void sighandler(int signum)
{
   printf("Caught signal %d, coming out...\n", signum);
   exit(1);
}
```

But when I press ctrl+c, it doesn't catch the signal. But when I make it run in background and send the SIGINT signal using kill command, it is working properly. Please help me anyone....

Comment: This has to do with your shell/terminal rather than your program

Comment: Check your terminal settings with `stty -a`.  The `intr = ^c` part means the `INTR` character is control-c.  The `isig` part means int, quit, and suspend special characters are enabled (when the terminal is in canonical (cooked) rather than raw mode).  `stty` checks its stdin, so you can `stty -a < /dev/pts/NN` to check the terminal your program is running on, while it's actually running.

Comment: Check this excerpt from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler/16891065#16891065  It is not safe to call all functions, such as printf, from within a signal handler. A useful technique is to use a signal handler to set a flag and then check that flag from the main program and print a message if required.

Comment: It's working fine in my system. As like Peter Cordes comment check with your terminal settings.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` and `exit` aren't safe to call inside a signal handler. See [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for the limited things you can do.

The immediate cause of your program's malfunction is likely that the file buffer for `stdout` didn't get flushed.

This change should fix it:

```
void sighandler(int signum)
{
   char msg[] = "Caught signal, coming out...\n";
   write( STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof msg );
   _exit(1); // Do not call atexit routines.
}
```

However, the better strategy is to avoid doing any real work inside the handler at all. Just set a flag and return.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>

void sighandler(int);
volatile sig_atomic_t gotsig = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t signum;

int main()
{
   signal(SIGINT, &sighandler);

   while(!gotsig) 
   {
      sleep(1); 
   }
   printf("Caught signal %d, coming out...\n", signum);
   exit(1);
}

void sighandler(int in_signum)
{
    gotsig = 1;
    signum = in_signum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading that `sigaction` is the preferred function to use instead of `signal`, which is not as portable (pretty sure it was from [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/) which is an essential reference in my opinion).

My first thought was that Ctrl+C might not send the `SIGINT` signal if the system is not POSIX compliant, so I made a test program to see what relevant signals I can raise. The answer by @Potatoswatter popped up while I was trying this out and it seem more relevant to your immediate question of not getting output. Regardless, here is a POSIX friendly source file to test four signals (`SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`, `SIGTSTP`, and `SIGQUIT`):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <unistd.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void sigHandler(int sig);
static int did_catch = 0;
static int sig_caught = 0;

int main() {

    struct sigaction sa;

    /* buidl sigaction struct */
    sa.sa_handler = sigHandler;
    if (sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask) != 0) { perror("\nsigemptyset"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    sa.sa_flags = 0;

    /* handle signals */
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) != 0) { perror("\nproblem adding SIGINT"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL) != 0) { perror("\nproblem adding SIGTERM"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    if (sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sa, NULL) != 0) { perror("\nproblem adding SIGQUIT"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    if (sigaction(SIGTSTP, &sa, NULL) != 0) { perror("\nproblem adding SIGTSTP"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    /* wait for signal */
    while (!did_catch) {
        pause();
    }

    /* check caught signals */
    if (sig_caught == SIGINT) printf("\nsignal is SIGINT\n");
    else if (sig_caught == SIGTERM) printf("\nsignal is SIGTERM\n");
    else if (sig_caught == SIGQUIT) printf("\nsignal is SIGQUIT\n");
    else if (sig_caught == SIGTSTP) printf("\nsignal is SIGTSTP\n");
    else printf("\nsignal captured is not listed\n");

    return 0;
}

void sigHandler(int sig) {
    sig_caught = sig;
    did_catch = 1;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `sigaction` is POSIX. `signal` is part of the C language standard, so it is more portable. The C library, by the way, is also included in POSIX.

Comment: OK thanks. I found the section I was thinking of in [TLPI](http://man7.org/tlpi/). It's in section **22.7** and basically states that old unreliable UNIX implementations of `signal` such as System V and old glibc behave unreliably and differently than newer implementations (different semantics) so `sigaction` is more reliable with a clearly defined implementation. The linux [signal man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) also suggests `sigaction`. In practice, I'd expect using `signal` is just fine on newer systems.